# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, error-handling, syntax-error

I do not know, what is wrong with this code:

```
function my_wpcf7_save($cfdata) {

$formtitle = $cfdata->title;
$formdata = $cfdata->posted_data;   

if ( $formtitle == 'contactform1') {

    // access data from the submitted form
    $formfield = $formdata['name'];

    // create a new post
    $newpost = array( 
                  'post_title' -> $formdata['name']);
                  'post_content' -> $formdata['message']);
                  'post_status' -> 'publish');

    $newpostid = wp_insert_post($newpost);

    // add meta data for the new post
    add_post_meta($newpostid, 'email', $formdata['email']);
    add_post_meta($newpostid, 'subject', $formdata['subject']);
}

}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_wpcf7_save',1);
```

I got the error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'** 
... for this line: 'post_title' -> $formdata['name']);

As far as I know, the syntax is right, isn't it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple syntax error. Use a proper text editor with syntax highlighting.


Comment: See http://php.net/array

Comment: i replaced -> with => and not working. I also removed the ";" with ","

Comment: And did you also remove the extra `(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the comment from mario in your question:

```
// create a new post
$newpost = array( 
              'post_title' => $formdata['name'],  <------------------ Here
              'post_content' => $formdata['message'], <-------------- Here
              'post_status' => 'publish');
```

Update: Also replace `->` with `=>`, as shown above.

Comment: still this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'

Comment: @MP, Please try again.  There was another problem, you were using `->` instead of `=>`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I managed with that later, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this:

```
$newpost = array( 
  'post_title' -> $formdata['name']);
  'post_content' -> $formdata['message']);
  'post_status' -> 'publish');
```

should be:

```
$newpost = array( 
  'post_title' => $formdata['name'],
  'post_content' => $formdata['message'],
  'post_status' => 'publish');
```

As it was you were closing the array and statement before you were actually finished declaring the array. That's what I think you were trying to do atleast.

Comment: still this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'